# NodeJS readFileSync and Regex the resulting text

Tags: node.js, regex

Looking to scrape the comments out of a JS file. Was thinking I can create a function to input a .js file, perform a RegExp match, and output an array of strings using fs.readFile() and string.match();

Here's an over-simplified example:

I have two files class.js (to read) and parse.js (to perform the text parsing)

class.js:

```
/*
    by: Mike Freudiger
*/

/**
* one
* @returns 'Hello World'
*/
function one () {
        return 'Hello World';
}

alert();

/* end of file */
```

parse.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\mikef\\Desktop\\node_regex_test\\class.js', 'utf8', function(err, doc) {
    var comments = doc.match(/(\/\*\*(.|\n)+?\*\/)/g);
    console.log(comments);
});
```

when I run node parse.js the console output is null.

However when I run the regex match on a multiline string, I get the expected output:

```
var doc = `/*
        by: Mike Freudiger
    */

    /**
    * one
    * @returns 'Hello World'
    */
    function one () {
            return 'Hello World';
    }

    alert();

    /* end of file */`
```

Any idea why the readFile() string would behave differently than a string literal?

...Also, I realize there may be a better way to get these comments out, with another npm package or something, but now I really just want to know why these two strings are different.

Comment: Could it be that your file uses `\r\n` or `\r` as line separators?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by vsemozhetbyt, it seems that newlines used in `class.js` file are either `\r\n` or `\r`.

One of the simplest (and fastest) way to match these newlines would be to use `[\s\S]` instead of `(.|\n)` in your regex.

Thus you get:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.readFile('C:\\Users\\mikef\\Desktop\\node_regex_test\\class.js', 'utf8', function(err, doc) {
    var comments = doc.match(/(\/\*\*[\s\S]+?\*\/)/g);
    console.log(comments);
});
```

Comment: That works!  That obviously means that new lines are represented differently in a file than a multi line string?  Could anyone point to documentation?

Comment: Template literals always use `\n`, even though you copy a text from a `\r\n` file and paste it in the source code in a template literal, after the parsing it will contain `\n` separators.

Comment: You can check it here: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html#_line-terminators-in-template-literals-are-always-lf-n . Or you can also check the more formal description from ECMAScript specification here : http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-tv-and-trv